# p:dataTable single selection radio button error : cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Primefaces 4.0

Hello, I'm trying to implement a `<p:dataTable>` with radio button single selection. The table is rendered right, but when U submit the page I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lpt.ef.besa.pe.common.api.TermDepositProduct; cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:977)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeSingleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:38)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:60)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:232)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
```

My Datatable code:

```
<p:dataTable var="product" value="#{availableTermDepositProducts.rows}" selection="#{form.product}"
            emptyMessage="#{i18n['messages.global.dataTable.emptyMessage']}" rowKey="#{product.id}">

            <p:column selectionMode="single" />
            ...columns
</p:dataTable>'
```

My backing bean:

```
public class TermDepositProductSubscriptionFormBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TermDepositProduct product;
    private String productId;
    private boolean automaticRenewal;
    private boolean interestCapitalization;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public boolean isAutomaticRenewal() {
        return automaticRenewal;
    }

    public void setAutomaticRenewal(boolean automaticRenewal) {
        this.automaticRenewal = automaticRenewal;
    }

    public boolean isInterestCapitalization() {
        return interestCapitalization;
    }

    public void setInterestCapitalization(boolean interestCapitalization) {
        this.interestCapitalization = interestCapitalization;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public TermDepositProduct getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(TermDepositProduct product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Why does it keep trying to cast to a collection if im using single selection?

-Thanks

Comment: You'd perhaps have more luck asking it directly to PrimeFaces. We're just PrimeFaces users not PrimeFaces developers. In the meanwhile, just use a collection/array as you probably already figured out.

Comment: You could always try a *newer* version and/or check the releasenotes there have been 24 4.0.x releases since then, 17 5.0.x and 11 5.1.x release.

Comment: Oh and btw, `[Lpt.ef.besa.pe.common.api.TermDepositProduct` is an array (**[L denotes that**), not a single item. So it tries to cast an array to a collection...

Comment: Thank you all for your help,  kukeltje you were right. I wasnt reading the error log with attention, i assumed it was trying to cast the selected item, but it was trying to cast the array to a collection.  
Im just gonna use a collection to fill the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Datatable Selection with Array is currently not supported, so im gonna fill the datatable with a collection.

I though Primefaces was trying to cast the Selected Item to a collection, instead it was trying to cast the Array i used to fill the datatable, hence the error. I wasnt reading the error log with attention.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ;-). But single selection should work with normal getters/setters of the single object type to. No need to use a collection for that.

Comment: Actually, single selection with radio button does not support arrays, you have to use a collection to fill the datatable, as stated by one of the primefaces developers in this post http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=41164

Comment: Ahhh... even I missed the 'populating' part. I only focussed on the [L and the getter/setter for the selection (where I could not see anything wrong) :-)